# Github switching master branch to main breaks my travis-ci build

Tags: git, github, travis-ci, git-branch

I'm using the same `.travis.yml` file (everything same except the defined values) between all my projects and they had been working for years.

Today I initiated a new project in Github (Go) and noticed that the default `master` branch is now named `main`. However, this switch breaks my travis-ci build. I'm getting

`Skipping a deployment with the bintray provider because this branch is not permitted: main`

I don't specific any branches in my `.travis.yml` file:

```sh
$ grep -i branch .travis.yml || echo not found
not found
```

How to fix it? Would adding `branch` specification in my `.travis.yml` within the following section fix the issue?

```
deploy:
  - provider: bintray
    user: myid
    key: ${BINTRAY_API_KEY}
    file: bintray-bin.json
    skip_cleanup: true
```

I'd better ask instead of triggering my travis-ci build over and over to find the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer but if someone face the same problem.

For a React deployment i just add branchers entry to specify the branch i want to deploy :

**.travis.yml:**

```
branches:
  only:
    - master
  except:
    - develop
```

the whole configuration looks like :

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "8"
cache: npm
branches:
  only:
    - master
  except:
    - develop
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: deploy
      script:
        - npm install -g firebase-tools
        - npm run build
        - firebase deploy --project "$projectId" --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"
```

**Note :** define the environment variables `projectId` and `FIREBASE_TOKEN` on the setting section on travis of the repo.

Look at this [article](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2019-05-30-setting-up-a-ci-cd-process-on-github)

Comment: Thanks Hannani, just for clarification, is your default branch named master or main?

Comment: Named master in my case
https://config.travis-ci.com/ref/job/branches